# Partial differential equation - wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We have the equation $u_{tt}= u_{xx}$ for $0<x<2 $ and $t>0$ subject to $u(x,0)= 0$, $u_t(x,0) = x$, $u(0,t)=t$, and $u_x(2,t) =t^2$.
Using variable separation method, we set $u(x,y)=X(x)T(t)$. We get T(0)=0 from the first condition. I am not able to conclude anything from other options. Is it better to use Fourier transforms for these kind of problems?

Comment: The problem is overdetermined. The two conditions $u(x,0)=0$ and $(\partial_t u)(x,0)=x$ already uniquely specify a solution.

Comment: If you were going to use separation of variables, you need to make the boundary conditions $u(0,t) = t$ and $u_{x}(2,t) = t^{2}$ _homogeneous_ i.e you need them to be of the form $u(0,t) = 0$ and $u_{x}(2,t) = 0$. If you want to make your boundary conditions homogeneous, let $u(x,t) = v(x,t) + t + xt^{2}$ and now you have the new PDE system in $v$ to solve \begin{align} v_{tt} &= v_{xx} - 2x \\ v(0,t) &= 0 \\ v_{x}(2,t) &= 0 \\ v(x,0) &= 0 \\ v_{t}(x,0) &= x-1 \end{align}

Comment: @mattos: I think then we can apply Duhamel’s method